# How to get notified when a specific file is deleted in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm looking for a way to monitor a file and trigger an event as soon the file was removed. Once it is removed I will replace/copy a new file and start the monitor again.

E.g.

```
watch "/tmp/fileToMonitor.txt"

// file deleted by some process
cp new_file "/tmp/fileToMonitor.tx"

// watch file again (repeat same steps..)
```

How can I do that with a bash script? Is this possible?

Comment: There's `auditd`. Do some research on it.

Comment: Also research inotify

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this with `inotifywait` utility (from `inotify-tools` package, under Debian at least).

`inotifywait` can take event names as arguments and wait for them to happen on monitored file or directory, before returning. In your case, you would need to use the `delete_self` event, to indicate that you want the program to return when monitored file is deleted.

So to copy a new file as soon as `/tmp/fileToMonitor.txt` is removed, you would do:

```
inotifywait -e delete_self "/tmp/fileToMonitor.txt" && cp new_file "/tmp/fileToMonitor.txt"
```

If you want to start monitoring again, you could put this inside a loop:

```
while true ; do
  inotifywait -e delete_self "/tmp/fileToMonitor.txt" \
    && cp new_file "/tmp/fileToMonitor.txt"
done
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome :) The `modify` event is very handy to recompile your files on change, by the way. In general this is what I use this tool for.